# How do I remove eventlisteners and objects from an array upon game completion?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have written a drag and drop game and, for the most part, it works.
It runs and does what I need it to do.
However, I cannot figure out two things.
How to remove the toy objects from the screen and re-add them after game over.
How to remove the event listeners for dragging/collision action after game over has initiated.
At the moment, after score is displayed you can still drop items in the toybox and make the score rise even when game over has been displayed.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?
I would love to figure this out but it is driving me crazy.
Any help would be great.

Here is my code ...

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.text.Font;
import flash.filters.GlowFilter;


public class MainGame extends MovieClip {

        const BG_SPEED:int = 5;
        const BG_MIN:int =  -550;
        const BG_MAX:int = 0;
        const PBG_SPEED:int = 3;            

        var bg:BackGround = new BackGround; 
        var paraBg:ParaBg = new ParaBg;
        var toybox:TargetBox = new TargetBox;
        var toy:Toy = new Toy;
        var tryAgain:TryAgain = new TryAgain;
        var cheer:Cheer = new Cheer;
        var eightBit:EightBit = new EightBit;
        var countDown:Number = 30;
        var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 30);
        var myText:TextField = new TextField;
        var myText2:TextField = new TextField;
        var myTextFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat;
        var myTextFormat2:TextFormat = new TextFormat;
        var font1:Font1 = new Font1;
        var kids:Kids = new Kids;
        var count:int = 0;
        var finalScore:int = 0;



        var score:Number = 0;

        var toy1:Toy1 = new Toy1;
        var toy2:Toy2 = new Toy2;
        var toy3:Toy3 = new Toy3;
        var toy4:Toy4 = new Toy4;
        var toy5:Toy5 = new Toy5;
        var toy6:Toy6 = new Toy6;
        var toy7:Toy7 = new Toy7;
        var toy8:Toy8 = new Toy8;
        var toy9:Toy9 = new Toy9;
        var toy10:Toy10 = new Toy10;
        var toy11:Toy11 = new Toy11;
        var toy12:Toy12 = new Toy12;
        var toy13:Toy13 = new Toy13;
        var toy14:Toy14 = new Toy14;
        var toy15:Toy15 = new Toy15;
        var toy16:Toy16 = new Toy16;
        var toy17:Toy17 = new Toy17;
        var toy18:Toy18 = new Toy18;
        var toy19:Toy19 = new Toy19;
        var toy20:Toy20 = new Toy20;

        var toyArray:Array = new Array(toy1, toy2, toy3, toy4, toy5, toy6, toy7, toy8, toy9, toy10, toy11, toy12, toy13, toy14, toy15, toy16, toy17, toy18, toy19, toy20);

    public function mainGame():void
    {
        trace("HI");
        eightBit.play(0, 9999);
        addChildAt(paraBg, 0);
        addChildAt(bg, 1);  
        addChildAt(kids, 2);
        kids.x = 310;
        kids.y = 200;
        addChild(toy);
        toy.x = 306;
        toy.y = 133;
        addChild(toybox);
        toybox.x = 295;
        toybox.y = 90;
    function addToys(xpos:int, ypos:int)
        {               
            addChild(toyArray[i]);
            toyArray[i].x = xpos;
            toyArray[i].y = ypos;   
        }

        for (var i:int = 0; i < toyArray.length; i++)
        {
            addToys(1140 * Math.random() + 20, 170 * Math.random() + 230);                  
        }
    }


        public function bgScroll (e:Event)
        {

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, arrayDrop);
            myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);
            myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerDone);
            myTimer.start();

            e.target.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, collision);

            if (stage.mouseX > 600 && bg.x > BG_MIN)
            {
                bg.x -= BG_SPEED;   
                paraBg.x -= PBG_SPEED;

                for (var m:int=0; m< toyArray.length; m++)
                {
                (toyArray[m] as MovieClip).x -=BG_SPEED
                }

            }
            else if (stage.mouseX < 50 && bg.x < BG_MAX)
            {
                bg.x += BG_SPEED;
                paraBg.x += PBG_SPEED;
                for (var j:int=0; j< toyArray.length; j++)
                {
                (toyArray[j] as MovieClip).x +=BG_SPEED
                }                           
            }
            for (var k:int = 0; k < toyArray.length; k++)
            {
                toyArray[k].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, arrayGrab);


            }           

                bg.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bgScroll);       


        } // End of BGScroll

    public function collision (e:Event)
            {           
                for (var l:int=0; l< toyArray.length; l++)
                    {                       
                        if (toyArray[l].hitTestObject(toy))
                        {
                            removeChild(toyArray[l]);
                            toyArray[l].x=100000;
                            toybox.gotoAndPlay(2);
                            cheer.play(1, 1);
                            score = score + 10;
                            trace(score);

                        }   

                        if (score == 200)
                        {
                            timerDone();
                            myTimer.stop();                     
                        }
                    }
            }

    public function arrayGrab(e:MouseEvent)
            {
                e.target.startDrag();
            }

    public function arrayDrop(e:MouseEvent)
            {
                stopDrag();

            }

    public function resetGame(e:Event):void {
        trace("CLICK");
            countDown = 30;
            myText.text = "0" + countDown.toString();
            myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerDone);
            myTimer.reset();
            removeChild(tryAgain);
            myText2.visible = false;
            score = 0;
        }

    public function countdown(e:TimerEvent):void
        {           

            if (countDown > 0)
            {
                countDown--;
            }
            if (countDown < 10)
            {
                myText.text = "0" + countDown.toString();
                myText.x = 270;
                displayText();
            }
            else if (countDown < 20 && countDown > 9)
            {
                myText.text = countDown.toString();
                myText.x = 280;
                displayText();
            }
            else
            {
                myText.text = countDown.toString();
                myText.x = 270;
                displayText();
            }           

        } // end of countdown function

        public function displayText():void
            {   
                myText.filters = [new GlowFilter(0x00FF00, 1.0, 5, 5, 4)];
                addChild(myText);
                myText.width = 500, myText.height = 50, myText.y = 10;      
                myTextFormat.size = 50, myTextFormat.font = font1.fontName;                 
                myText.setTextFormat(myTextFormat);
            }

        public function displayText2():void
            {   myText2.filters = [new GlowFilter(0xFF0000, 1.0, 5, 5, 4)];
                addChild(myText2);
                myText2.width = 500, myText2.height = 35, myText2.x = 204, myText2.y = 200;     
                myTextFormat2.size = 30, myTextFormat2.font = font1.fontName;                   
                myText2.setTextFormat(myTextFormat2);
            }

            public function timerDone(e:TimerEvent=null):void
            {                           
                if (countDown == 0)
                {
                    count = 0;
                    finalScore = score;
                }
                else
                {                   
                    count = (30) - (myTimer.currentCount);
                    finalScore = (count * 10) + (score);

                }

                myText.text = "GAME OVER!";
                myText.x = 195;
                displayText();                          
                myText2.text = "Your score = " + (finalScore);
                displayText2();
                addChild(tryAgain);
                tryAgain.x = 300;
                tryAgain.y = 300;
                tryAgain.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, resetGame);
            }

} // End of class
```

} //End of package

Comment: You could try something like in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325025/how-to-automatically-delete-event-listener-from-an-object-in-as3) answer. When a sprite is added to stage you place a listener on the sprite for `Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE`. Inside the removed from staged event you remove all other listeners to stop circular reference memory leaks. Then you should be able to call on the game sprite `.removeChildren();`

Comment: I see you are still using nested functions...  Why do you punish yourself?

Comment: you need to loop through the array of toys (just like you do to add them) and remove them `removeChild(toyArray[i])` AND remove their listener(s) `toyArray[i].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, arrayGrab)`

Comment: @LDMS ... actually, I have a file with a class and all seperate functions but I couldn't make it work.
I planned on trying to get this one to work and then (hopefully) go back to my seperate class and call that over.
Figured it was easier to copy/paste this code over than confuse matters.

Comment: @LDMS - Ok, so I am using the separate class way and making some headway.
However, I am tired and will tackle it again tomorrow!
Thanks for your advice. :)

Comment: @Lex - I haven't even begun to use sprites yet. LOL
I'm still a beginner! But I will bear this in mind for when I do understand them.

Comment: @LDMS - Tried looping through array to remove the objects and it didn't work. :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind ... solved it.
Easiest was was to change

```
function addToys(xpos:int, ypos:int)
    {               
        addChild(toyArray[i]);
        toyArray[i].x = xpos;
        toyArray[i].y = ypos;   
    }
```

To

```
function addToys(xpos:int, ypos:int)
        {               
            stage.addChild(toyArray[i]);
            toyArray[i].x = xpos;
            toyArray[i].y = ypos;   
        }
```

And then, in the `timerDone function I added this`if statement ...

```
for (var m = 0; m < toyArray.length; m++) {
                    if (stage.contains(toyArray[m])) {
                    stage.removeChild(toyArray[m]);

                         }
```

Worked a treat!